# Python random генератор чисел

Tags: python, случайные-числа

```py
import random

while True:
    numG = random.randint(0, 10)
    numG = round(numG)
    numQ = random.randint(0, 10)
    numQ = round(numQ)

    k = 0
    if numQ == numG:
        k += 1
        print("Mission complete!")
        print("Число раз {} {} {}".format(k, numG, numQ))
        break
    elif numQ != numG:
        k += 1
```

Почему происходит генерация одинаковых цифр в две разные переменные , и как сделать чтобы генерация была разная?

Comment: В каком месте заканчивается цикл while? А чтобы увидеть одинаковые случайные числа или нет, нужно напечатать их сразу после генерации, а не пихать в код с кривой логикой и потом делать такие же криве выводы.

Comment: k=0 надо в первую строку перед циклом while иначе у тебя каждый раз k=1 показывает. Еще должно быть import random и отступ после while.

Comment: В округлении целого числа до целого тоже смысла нет.

Comment: break зачем? Разве он не в циуле должен быть?

Comment: @Serhii  зачем вы сделали коду очевидно неверное форматирование? Не нужно лезть в чужой код и исправлять его так, как вам вдруг показалось верным.

Comment: numG и numQ были влево приплюснуты, а не в цикле вайл. я всего лишь табом их подвинул. если неверно я что-то сделал, то зачем мое форматирование приняли? но даже если это так, скажите, где неверно и примите мои извенения @Эникейщик

Comment: @Serhii приняли потому что никто не вникал. Запустите этот свой новый код и расскажите потом, что произойдет, когда он закончится. Если доживёте до того момента

Comment: нужно подвинуть еще вправо часть кода видимо.недаром там break был. ну извините @Эникейщик

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random

k = 0
while True:
    numG = random.randint(0, 10)
    numG = round(numG)
    numQ = random.randint(0, 10)
    numQ = round(numQ)

    if numQ == numG:
        k += 1
        print("Mission complete!")
        print("Число раз {} {} {}".format(k, numG, numQ))
        break
    elif numQ != numG:
        k += 1
```

Происходило обнуление `k` на каждой итерации цикла, нужно единоразово присвоить ей 0 до `while`

Ну, и правильнее было бы сделать так:

```
import random

k = 0
while True:
    numG = random.randint(0, 10)
    numQ = random.randint(0, 10)

    k += 1
    if numQ == numG:
        print("Mission complete!")
        print("Число раз {} {} {}".format(k, numG, numQ))
        break
```